# How would I sort and display data in a tabular way with entities gathered from a Linq request?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel, tabular

How would I display data from the following database entity in a format that looks like a table:

```
public class Attendance
{
    public int AttendanceID { get; set; }
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public int AttendanceDay { get; set; }
    public bool Present { get; set; }
    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

I would want to find all rows in the Attendance db entry that had CourseID == x; So I would use something like:

```
AttendanceData = Attendance.Where(s => s.CourseID == x); // I think
```

Then I would need to be able to sort this information in my view to display it in a way that makes sense.  I would want to have a data on screen with all of the present/not present values sorted in a table with StudentIDs listed on the left and AttendanceDays listed accross the top.

How would I sort and display this information?

UPDATE:

Using the following code (along with Mvc WebGrid) - I can get a grid of some sort to appear in my view.

Controller:

```
IEnumerable<Attendance> model = db.Attendance.Where(s => s.CourseID == 4);
return View(model);
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.Attendance>

<div>
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model, defaultSort: "Name");
}

    @grid.GetHtml()

</div>
```

However, the grid is not organized in a manner that is useful for my needs.

I want the top of my displayed table to read:

Day 1 | Day 2 | Day 3 | etc until the max value of "Attendance Day" (which is dictated at the creation of a Course that a student signs up for).

I want the left side of the displayed table to read:
Student ID 1
Student ID 5
Student ID 6
Student ID etc . .   until all of the students within the data set have been displayed.

I think I need to use something along the lines of this in my controller:

```
var model = from s in db.Attendance
                        where s.CourseID == 4
                        group s.AttendanceDay by s.StudentID into t
                        select new
                        {
                            StudentID = t.Key,
                            Days = t.OrderBy(x => x)
                        };
return View(model);
```

But I need an IEnumerable<> returned to my view using Mvc WebGrid -- I am getting somewhere, just still a little lost along the way.  Can I get a nudge in the right direction?

Comment: I have updated my post above to include progress I have made.

Answer (score 1):

For a fairly typical set of requirements, it sounds like this would be a good candidate for the ASP.NET WebGrid.  It's flexible, allows for paging, sorting, formatting, etc.  I've used it for a few projects and works just like any of the other HTML helpers that you're probably used to in ASP.NET MVC.

[Here's a good starting place.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288075.aspx)

Comment: That definitely got me started - at least now I have an improperly formatted attendance table instead of no table at all.  Now I need to learn how to tweak this a lot.  Thank you sincerely.